# How to run Python in komodo

Tags: python-3.x, editor, interpreter, komodoedit

I am completely new to Python and wanted to try this code from the tutorial:

```
istrue = 1
if istrue:
    print ("be carefull!")
```

The code itself should be fine, but I can not find any way to execute this code inside the editor [Komodo-Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)

I am used to Visual Studio and QtCreator (experienced C++/Qt developer). I would expect a menu for debugging and a command such as 'start debugging' which should open a console or use a console inside the editor. I would in any case refuse to use a dos console because then the whole idea of using an IDE would be useless.

If other Python IDEs would be more useful (on windows, no costs) I could switch to another one (except for vim/emacs).

Comment: I use [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) - there's a built-in interpreter, and you can execute selected code in a file by  pressing Ctrl+F7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to use Komodo edit, but not anymore as It's more of a text editor than an IDE. I reccomend using Ninja-IDE or Eclipse with PyDev. But if you insist on using Konodo Edit, here's an option:
Go here: Toolbox > Add > New Command...
in the top field enter the name 'Run Python file' or something else. Then go to the 'command' field and enter this:

```
%(python) "%F"
```

Optionally, you could also specify key binding for fast python executing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Komodo Edit version 9 and 10. Matthias' method work for the version 9. Version 10, I couldn't see the option to choose the Interpreter.